# wavesurfer.js trying to style handles in regions

Tags: wavesurfer.js

I am using wavesurfer.js 4.6.0 and can create regions.  I am able to change the background color of the region and dynamically set whether a region loops or not but I would also like to change the color of the left and right handles for the region.

The documentation does not show a way to set this when creating a region but if I look at the code in gitHub it has:

```
this.loop = Boolean(params.loop);
this.color = params.color || 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)';
// The left and right handleStyle properties can be set to 'none' for
// no styling or can be assigned an object containing CSS properties.
this.handleStyle = params.handleStyle || {
    left: {},
    right: {}
};
```

which shows how the looping and color are set.  It also shows that it would take a handleStyle so that you can style the left and right handle but I cannot seem to get it to work.

Is this possible to do this? If so does someone have an example of how to set it.

I am on Angular 11.2.6 and Node 10.15.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  If the line:

```
this.handleStyle = params.handleStyle || {
```

to

```
this.handleStyle = params.params.handleStyle || {
```

It will work.  We decided we needed some other modifications to the regions so I have just copied the regions plug-in to our code tree to make the changes.